# SQL query to return ids that only signed up but didn't take any other action

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `event` table that looks like this.

```
| id | event   | date       |
|----|---------|------------|
| 1  | sign up | 28/01/2022 |
| 1  | log in  | 29/01/2022 |
| 1  | delete  | 30/01/2022 |
| 2  | sign up | 31/01/2022 |
| 3  | log in  | 01/02/2022 |
| 4  | sign up | 02/02/2022 |
| 4  | NULL    | 03/02/2022 |
```

I want to write a query that selects distinct `ids` and  that only signed up and did not carry out any other event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id from t
group by id 
having count(distinct event)=1 and max(event)='sign up'
```

or if you want `null` as a value:

`having count(distinct coalesce(event,'x'))=1 and max(event)='sign up'`

Answer (score 0):

You can write this with a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where not exists (select * 
                  from the_table t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2."date" > t1."date"
                    and t2.event <> t1.event)
  and t1.event = 'sign up';
```

You did not specify if the `NULL` event for `id = 4` is to be taken as "something else" or "nothing".